# `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am creating

```
bundler gem --test=rspec MyGem.
```

in which I'm getting the repository structure.

When I try to run the `rspec` code I get the following error:

```
 `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

I then try to apply require relative but I still get an error:

```
sheetal@ubuntu:~/sheetal/spec$ rspec sheetal_spec.rb 
\/home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/sheetal/sheetal/spec/sheetal_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're running the specs from the `spec` folder. This messes up the load path. Run specs from the root of your project: `~/sheetal`.

```
rspec spec/sheetal_spec.rb
```

Rspec adds the `spec` and `lib` folders to the load path automatically. If you're already in the `spec` folder, rspec is going to add `spec/spec` to the load path instead.

Assuming that you have your code in the `lib` folder, you would have to add both `.` and `../lib` to the load path if you want to run your tests in the `spec` folder.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper ..I am able to run it now from my folder it self