# Ruby On Rails Rspec 'require' doesn't find the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

File system looks like this:

[image: File system]

**page_spec.rb:**

```
require 'rails_helper'
  RSpec.describe Page, type: :model do
    ...
  end
```

**rails_helper.rb**'s require part:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

When I try to run **`rspec page_spec.rb`** it says that "cannot load such file rails_helper".
When i change to `require '../rails_helper'`, it says "Cannot load spec_helper". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line 
`require 'rails_helper'`in page_spec.rb file to `require_relative '../rails_helper'`.

Comment: this is kinda helped, but i should run rspec only from the root dir.

Comment: yes Arthur, you need to run rspec from the root dir.

Comment: Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163508/require-cannot-load-such-file-spec-helper-loaderror)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163508/require-cannot-load-such-file-spec-helper-loaderror) is explanation of why you should run rspec from root dir.

Comment: Here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/392724/puppet-rspec-no-such-file-to-load-rspec-puppet-loaderror](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392724/puppet-rspec-no-such-file-to-load-rspec-puppet-loaderror) is an answer which say putting `require 'rubygems'` at the top of file 'spec_helper.rb' should resolve your issue of "can't load spec_helper". I haven't tried it. Give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `rspec` command from the root directory `rspec spec/models/page_spec.rb`