# Cannot execute rspec using bundle exec rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am pretty new at programming, just learning for a few months, and I have been trying to run rspec for a ruby project I am working on so I can become more familiar with TDD and when I try to run rspec using bundle exec rspec, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        14: from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        13: from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        12: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        11: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
         9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
         8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
         7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
         6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `process_options_into'
         5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `each'
         4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:110:in `block in process_options_into'
         3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `requires='
         2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `each'
         1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `block in requires='
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

I think there may be something wrong with my PATH, as i had to install my gems using sudo command. When trying to make sure bundler was updated I got the following warning:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using byebug 11.1.1
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /usr/local/bin
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/build_info
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/cache
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/doc
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/specifications
Using diff-lcs 1.3
Using rspec-support 3.2.2
Using rspec-core 3.2.3
Using rspec-expectations 3.2.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.2.1
Using rspec 3.2.0
```

my computer is currently running the most recent version of ubuntu and I am using VScode if that provides any help. My current PATH seems like it has many repeated instances of the same thing and I don't know if that is contributing to anything.

My current PATH:

```
/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/home/tom/.rbenv/shims:/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/home/tom/.rbenv/shims:/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/home/tom/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

any help is greatly appreciated! I am so tired of getting hung up by this and trying to google around figuring out whats wrong hasnt been helping.

Comment: `cannot load such file -- spec_helper` - do you have it? I think it's supposed to lay in the `/spec` directory.

Comment: yes, I just looked, it appears spec_helper is indeed in its location within spec directory.

Comment: can this be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167361/299774 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`require': cannot load such file -- spec\_helper (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163508/require-cannot-load-such-file-spec-helper-loaderror)

Comment: This is not related to your shell's `PATH` env var, rather the `spec_helper` file is not available on your require path.